# Is there a way to make search-based playlists at Amarok 1.4?

Tags: linux, music, playlists, amarok

I have almost 2 weeks of music in my computer, and I wanna rate all those musics...

I use a playlist based on my entire collection + this search: "rating:=0".
So I can use global shortcuts to rate the music that's playing and keep working/surfing...

But sometimes I need to clear my playlist... And it's painful to reload all those files into a playlist and filter it again.

Is there any way I can save the combo "all music + rating:=0" to a dynamic playlist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a smart playlist by choosing the playlist tab, then right clicking on "Smart Playlists", then give it a name, choose "Match Any of the following Conditions" and then enter "Rating" "is" "not rated".

This will automatically be the entire collection + your search. If you want to limit this, to a smaller number, then create a new dynamic playlist using that smart playlist. It will still eventually get through the whole collection, but won't have all of them listed in the active playlist.

Comment: haha with your answer I figured out why it wasn't working; I have already done this, but... I was misusing 'score', not 'rating'. In portuguese both are so similar. xD thank you =D